# .Net: Does controller have to have file name corresponding to URL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-controls

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs) on .Net controllers, and it says "imagine that you enter the following URL into the address bar of your browser: http://localhost/Product/Index/3. In this case, a controller named ProductController is invoked."

**What I Want To Know:**

In order to successfully hit `http://localhost/Product/Index/3`, do you need a controller called `ProductController` specifically?

Comment: to understand this you should understand the routing https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary. You can use Route Attribute.

```
[Route("new-name-for-product")]
public class ProductController{

}
```

now you have to use http://localhost/new-name-for-product/Index/ this URL to invoke ProductController.
If you want to use one or more parameters with this URL you have to use different route templates for ActionMethod. Example below.

```
[Route("new-name-for-product")]
public class ProductController
{

// http://localhost/new-name-for-product/3/ will show product details based on id
// http://localhost/new-name-for-product/Index/3/ will show product details based on id

[HttpGet]
[Route("/{id}")]
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
// your code
}

// you can use a different action method name. 
// http://localhost/details/3/ will show product details based on id
// but parameter name (Ex: id) and the id inside route template the spelling must be the same.

[HttpGet]
[Route("details/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetById(int id)
{
// your code
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In ASP.Net Core, routing can be configured either as conventional routing or as attribute routing.

**Conventional routing** is configured as below:

```
routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Here, the first path segment maps to the controller name, 
the second maps to the action name,
the third segment is used for an optional id used to map to a model entity.

As a convention, controller file name is usually same as controller class name.
Hence, In conventional routing, url will match with filename.

The URL http://localhost/Products/Index matches below action method in ProductsController.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost("Index")]     // Matches 'Products/Index'  
   public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Attribute Routing**

With attribute routing the controller name and action names play no role in which action is selected. 
Hence, it is independent of file name.

The URL http://localhost/Items/All matches below action method in ProductsController.

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
   [Route("Items/All")]
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

Similarly, [Route] attribute can be added at both Controller and action methods. The same URL http://localhost/Items/All matches the action method shown below:

```
[Route("Items")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
       [Route("All")]
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
          return View();
       }
    }
```

For more details, you can refer to microsoft docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1